# XML parsing using XMLstreamreader

Tags: apex, xml

I am trying to parse through an XML which looks something  like

```
       <e:UDFs>
            <e:UDF name="Comments_20for_20Approvers">Cloning req 379023 - bypassing approvals</e:UDF>
            <e:UDF name="Delivery_20Model">
                <e:UDSElement>
                    <e:Description>
                        <e:value locale="en">Platinum</e:value>
                    </e:Description>
                </e:UDSElement>
            </e:UDF>
            <e:UDF name="Incentive_20Plan_20Code">
                <e:UDSElement>
                    <e:Description>
                        <e:value locale="en">RRP</e:value>
                    </e:Description>
                </e:UDSElement>
            </e:UDF>
            <e:UDF name="Job_Code">ICO050</e:UDF>
            <e:UDF name="Justification">
                <e:UDSElement>
                    <e:Description>
                        <e:value locale="en">Budgeted New</e:value>
                    </e:Description>
                </e:UDSElement>
            </e:UDF>
            <e:UDF name="Range_20Maximum"/>
            <e:UDF name="Target">1000</e:UDF>
            <e:UDF name="Underutilization_20Status">
                <e:UDSElement>
                    <e:Description>
                        <e:value locale="en">Underutilized for Minorities</e:value>
                    </e:Description>
                </e:UDSElement>
            </e:UDF>
        </e:UDFs>
```

As u can see there are several tags with tag named 'UDF' with different attributes like "Comments_20for_20Approvers" , "Delivery_20Model" and so on.

I want to parse through this XML and store values of these tags in different variables.
For example value of  in a variable called comments,  in a variable called incentive.

I want to use XMLstramreader. Following is my XMLstream

```
  Xmlstreamreader reader = new Xmlstreamreader(xmlBody);
```

Following is my code to go through the 'reader'

```
 while(reader.hasNext())
      {
        if (<check of a particular attribute>)
            {
             //do something

        }
      reader.next();
    }
```

Not sure how to look for attribute value in the IF statement above.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It might be worth better qualifying your question to be something like 'XML parsing attributes using XMLstreamreader'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the Apex documentation [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_xml_XmlStream_reader.htm), you use the **getAttributeLocalName** method to determine this, but only on start element or attribute element events. Adapting the sample given in the documentation you can see this method in action below.

```
while(reader.hasNext()) {
    if (reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.START_ELEMENT) {
        if ('UDF' == reader.getLocalName()) {
            System.debug(reader.getAttributeValue(null, 'name'));
        }
    }
    reader.next();
}
```

**Text Handling**. If you want to retrieve the test content of an element, you need to call getText() but only hasTest() returns true, e.g. when getEventType() == XmlTag.Characters. The documentation states that hasText() returns true and thus getText() works only when...

> Returns true if the current event has text, false otherwise The following XML events have text: characters, entity reference, comment and space.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Fawcett, this was really helpful. I am able to get to the desired tags. Now I have to pull text values from these tags. Is getText() best way to do it? This function will throw an exception as the Tag is a START_ELEMENT.

Comment: Thats correct, the documentation states when its possible to call getText(), see the hasText() method. I've updated my answer to reflect this additional query. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Your very welcome, if this has answered your question don't forget to accept it. Thanks!